# White/Gold vs Blue/Black dress

Tags: eyes, perception

So I'm sure you've all seen the dress photo where people see the dress as either White and Gold or Blue and Black.

It has essentially 'split' the internet because some people see the dress and they think that it is coloured blue and black, whereas the other half think that it is white and gold. It is trending on most social media sites as people fight about what the colour difference is.

So my question is why do different peoples eyes perceive different colours in this picture specifically?

For reference the photo with a color breakdown can be found [here](http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Unknown.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you test what color different people perceive?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5728/how-can-you-test-what-color-different-people-perceive)

Comment: Sorry, I meant this as a specific question for this photo, not just in general. As far as I can tell, perceptive difference is totally random.

Comment: Whether you see it as blue/black or white/gold depends on how you interpret the spectrum of lighting in the room. I would guess that different interpret that differently based on the subtle cues available in the rest of the picture. But I don't have a solid explanation of what those differences might be or why people might cue on different aspects of the image.

Comment: U did put up the pic later so you can hardly blame me for closing it as a duplicate

Comment: True. Not blaming in the slightest, simply clarifying what I meant.

Comment: Please add more information about the background of the question otherwise it is likely to be closed as unclear

Comment: It's a possible duplicate of http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9405/what-color-is-this-dress-and-why on Cog Sci.SE and it has been quite neatly addressed there in an answer.

Comment: Two popular articles on this: http://www.dogonews.com/2015/3/6/white-and-gold-or-blue-and-black-the-great-dress-debate and http://www.wired.com/2015/02/science-one-agrees-color-dress/